# ERROR: Array to string convertion laravel 6

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-6, jsonarray

Estoy trabajando con DATATABLE y quiero llamar a un procedimiento almacenado desde la **API.php** en  Laravel. El resultado de mi procedimiento almacenado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo en mi API.php:

```
Route::get('empleadosFull',function(){
   $MisEmpleados = DB::SELECT("CALL MisEmpleados");    
   return datatables()
    ->$MisEmpleados
    ->toJson();
    });
```

pero me muestra un mensaje de error **Array to string conversion**. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Pues no utilizo mucho `DB` para hacer consultas pero si aplicas primero `all()` antes de `->toJson()`, asi: `->$MisEmpleados->all()->toJson();`;

Comment: No muestra ningun dato

Comment: La imagen que muestras es un `dd` de `$misEmpledos`?

Comment: asi es, se el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado

Comment: Con Datatable te refieres a [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)? Si es así, podrias probar con algo más pareceido a lo que muestran en la documentación. Por ej `return datatables()->of($MisEmpleados)->toJson();`o `return datatables()->query($MisEmpleados)->toJson();`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Gracias funcionó!!, se me paso el ->of($MisEmpleados)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como muestras en la imagen, esta consulta:

```
$MisEmpleados = DB::SELECT("CALL MisEmpleados");
```

Te devueve un array de objetos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero luego intentas pasar ese array como el nombre de una propiedad al objeto `DataTables`:

```
return datatables()
        ->$MisEmpleados
        ->toJson();
```

De ahí el mensaje de error:

> Array to string conversion

Pues el nombre de una propiedad se pasa como `string`, y no un `array`:

```
$propiedad = 'el_nombre_de_alguna_propiedad';

return datatables()
        ->$propiedad
        ->toJson();
```

Para pasarle al objeto `DataTables` un `array` con los datos que quieres mostrar en la tabla, debes usar alguno de los métodos o sintaxis que tiene la librería. Por ejemplo:

```
return datatables()->of($MisEmpleados)->toJson();

return datatables()->query($MisEmpleados)->toJson();

return datatables($MisEmpleados)->toJson();
```

Fuente: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables